# When input value cannot be found in binary search

Tags: binary-search

```
def binary_search(arr, target):
    low, high = 0, len(arr) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        print(f"current range: {low+1}~{high+1}")
        print(f"current mid: {arr[mid]}")

        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < target:
            print(f"target {target} is bigger than {arr[mid]}.")
            low = mid + 1
        elif arr[mid] > target:
            print(f"target {target} is smaller than {arr[mid]}.")
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return -1


numbers = [str(i) for i in range(1, 101)]

target_number = input("Enter the numbe: ")

index = binary_search(numbers, target_number)

if index != -1:
    print(f"Found {target_number}! ")
else:
    print(f"{target_number} not found.")
```

If you enter a number other than 1 to 100, the binary search cannot proceed any longer, so I want to return -1 and display the last line of the code.

For example, when you enter 105, 105 is greater than 50, so it becomes 51 to 100, and 105 is greater than 75, so it becomes 76 to 100... and so on, and eventually it becomes 100. The initial range is 1 to 100, but since there is no input value, it returns -1 and prints that it cannot be found!

But it doesn't work that way. I don't know what the problem is.
help!! thankyou

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

```
def binary_search(arr, target):
    low, high = 0, len(arr) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        print(f"current range: {low+1}부터 {high+1}")
        print(f"current mid: {arr[mid]}")

        if (
            mid == len(arr) - 1 and
            arr[mid] != target
        ):
            return -1

        if arr[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < target:
            print(f"target {target} is bigger than {arr[mid]}.")
            low = mid + 1
        elif arr[mid] > target:
            print(f"target {target} is smaller than {arr[mid]}.")
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            return -1
```

you also set this nums as string , i changed to integers

```
numbers = [i for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Comment: thank you! but this doesn't work either...